# When to use Count(PK_ID) and when to use system tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We can use either `count(<column_name>)` or system tables to get the number of rows in a table.
Then where to use which one?

Thanks
Devi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `COUNT(*)` (without any `WHERE` conditions) starts to take more than about 10 seconds, that's when I usually cancel the query, and start using the system tables from then onwards. Obviously, if there are `WHERE` conditions, then you can only obtain the answer via `COUNT(*)` (or `COUNT(<column>)`)

Once a table is large enough that `COUNT(*)` isn't performing well, you don't generally need an exact answer anyway.

Comment: On some systems (e.g. PostgreSQL), the stats allow explain to return a reasonable estimate of rows even with where clauses if they're close enough to reality.

Comment: How big must be table be to take around 10 sec?

Comment: @Magnus - it depends on your hardware, width of rows, etc, but I've seen it happening with tables with 10s of millions of rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use the system tables/planer estimates when a (quick) approximate number of rows is acceptable. This requires that the table stats are reasonably accurate.

Comment: Is there any situation where the table statistics will not be accurate in sys table?

Comment: That depends on the system. In PostgreSQL, for instance, the stats are unreliable until you fill a few disk pages and manually run `analyze`. Or when you do a huge batch inserts, updates and deletes without running `analyze` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT()` whenever all you need is a row count from any one table.  Use system tables only if you need more information other than row count (such as space used and what not).

Comment: On the other hand - determining the *exact* row count using `COUNT(*)` can take a loooong time on larger tables - maybe getting an approximate numbers instantly from the system catalog views is good enough